# how to divide NSMutableArray array into two seperate arrays or two mutable arrays in objective C, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an nsmutable array with 4 objects.no I want to divide that objects into two arrays(or two mutable arrays) based on a condition.

```
for  (NSDictionary *final in SectorsArray)
{
    FinalFlightData *ffd = [FinalFlightData new];
    ffd.flightnumber = [final objectForKey:@"FLI_NUM"];
    ffd.airlineCode = [final objectForKey:@"ARL_COD"];

    ffd.departureAirport = [final objectForKey:@"DepartureAirport"];
    ffd.departureDay = [final objectForKey:@"DepartureDay"];
    ffd.departureDate = [final objectForKey:@"DepartureDate"];
    ffd.departureTime = [final objectForKey:@"DepartureTime"];

    ffd.arrivalAirport = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalAirport"];
    ffd.arrivalDay = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalDay"];
    ffd.arrivalDate = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalDate"];
    ffd.arrivalTime = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalTime"];




    [testingArray addObject:ffd];
}
```

so this testing nsmutable array has four objects.now I want to like this.

```
OutboundArray = [NSMutableArray array];
InboundArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *myString;

if([myString isEqualtoString:@"false"])
{
  //in here I want to put first two objects of testingArray into OutboundArray and last two objects of testingArray into InboundArray

}

else if([myString isEqualtoString:@"true"])
{
  //in here I want to put first three objects of testingArray into OutboundArray and last object of testingArray into InboundArray
}
else
{
  //in here I want to put first  object of testingArray into OutboundArray and last three objects of testingArray into InboundArray
}
```

how can I do this.hope your help.thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
if (testingArray.count >= 3)
{
    if([myString isEqualToString:@"false"])
    {
        //in here I want to put first two objects of testingArray into OutboundArray and last two objects of testingArray into InboundArray

        [OutboundArray addObjectsFromArray:[testingArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]];
        [InboundArray addObjectsFromArray:[testingArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(testingArray.count - 2, 2)]];

    }
    else if([myString isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
        //in here I want to put first three objects of testingArray into OutboundArray and last object of testingArray into InboundArray

        [OutboundArray addObjectsFromArray:[testingArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
        [InboundArray addObject:testingArray.lastObject];

    }
    else
    {
        //in here I want to put first  object of testingArray into OutboundArray and last three objects of testingArray into InboundArray

        [OutboundArray addObject:testingArray.firstObject];
        [InboundArray addObjectsFromArray:[testingArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(testingArray.count - 3, 3)]];
    }
}
else if (testingArray.count == 2)
{
    [OutboundArray addObject:testingArray.firstObject];
    [InboundArray addObject:testingArray.lastObject];
```

}

Comment: this works.but please tell me if the testingArray count is 2, how to put first object to onbound array and second object to inbound array.I got error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method.  You can generalize as needed.

```
NSArray *a = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];

NSMutableArray *a1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *a2 = [NSMutableArray array];

int limit = YES ? 3 : 1;

[a  enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx < limit) {
        [a1 addObject:obj];
    } else {
        [a2 addObject:obj];
    }
}];
```

Here's a second method, which avoids an explicit loop.  This one requires a true split, whereas the first is easily modified to allow arbitrary routing between arrays.

```
NSArray *a = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];

NSMutableArray *a1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *a2 = [NSMutableArray array];

int limit = YES ? 3 : 1;

NSRange a1range = NSMakeRange(0, limit);
NSRange a2range = NSMakeRange(limit, a.count - limit);

a1 = [[a subarrayWithRange:a1range] mutableCopy];
a2 = [[a subarrayWithRange:a2range] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add objects in OutboundArray or InboundArray from testingArray  i.e for first condition just use index 0 and 1 for first two object for OutboundArray and index 2 and 3 for InboundArray.Just use same in other conditions accordingly.@Note first check objects in testingArray before fetching from indexes otherwise it will crash.Always start variable name with small case:)

```
if(firstCondition)
{
  [OutboundArray addObject:[testingArray objectAtIndex:0]];
  [OutboundArray addObject:[testingArray objectAtIndex:1]];
  [InboundArray addObject:[testingArray objectAtIndex:2]];
  [InboundArray addObject:[testingArray objectAtIndex:3]];

}
```